# Auto POST when visit the page AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".district").change(function () {
        var d_id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'd_id=' + d_id;


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax-district.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $(".districtsub").html(html);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

This is the code I've used to retrieve data from option. If someone selected a district it will show to them the area they selected. What I've done is there will be a area always selected in option through the database
I want that it to show what area selected when person first visit to that page.

What I want is to automatically process when person visit the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger a change immediately:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".district").change(function () {
        var d_id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'd_id=' + d_id;


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax-district.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $(".districtsub").html(html);
            }
        });

    }).trigger('change');
});
```